# SMTP ERROR: Не отправляется сообщение на mail.ru

Tags: php

Помогите мне, пожалуйста: php скрипт на mail.ru не отправляет письмо, но на другие почтовые ящики все нормально отправляет, а мне нужен на mail.ru. А хостинг взял из cishost.ru за 10 рублей в месяц, а п.у ispi manager.

Текст ошибки:

> The message identifier is: 1S2l8y-0006Am-7C The subject of the message is: Новый подписчик на рассылку — SkyScript The date of the message is: Wed, 29 Feb 2012 19:08:40 +0400
>
> The address to which the message has not yet been delivered is:
> admin@skystudio.ru Delay reason: SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:admin@skystudio.ru: host mx25.valuehost.ru
>
> [217.112.35.101]: 450 4.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your hostname,
>
> [92.38.198.38] No action is required on your part. Delivery attempts will continue for some time, and this warning may be repeated at intervals if the message remains undelivered. Eventually the mail delivery software will give up, and when that happens, the message will be returned to you.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы письма доходили на mail.ru, должно выполнятся несколько условий.

1. Адрес отправителя должен
       принадлежать серверу, с которого
       уходит письмо
2. Необходимо указывать, корректный, 5-й параметр для функции `mail()`
3. Письмо не должно попасть под спам фильтр mail.ru

Comment: но если так он не должен попаст в спам?

Comment: Не должен, но может.

Comment: Текст ошибки добавлен в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно содержимое email письма попало под спам фильтр mail.ru.